# Menu layouts for a web page

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a web page for ECDL courses, for the menu I thought I'd set tens of pentagonal boxes. For the position on the page there are no problems. The problem is when I go into the text, I set a certain size of the box and I want the text centered, can anyone explain the code syntax to use?
This is the screen of the problem:
[image]

Comment: Could you paste the code into your question, so we can see how the layout is generated?

Comment: #quinta-sezzione
  {color: blue;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 170px;
  position:absolute;
        left:750px;
        top:720px;  
  }

Comment: <div id ="quinta-sezzione">
      
  <p align = "center"> ---???---</p>
 
 </div>

Comment: now, is all ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in the css of the text container.

```
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution :

```
text-align: center;
```

**center**

The inline contents are centered within the line box.

The text-align CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align?v=example